# Schema matching using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm facing the following problem of integrating data from another company  (data base) to an internal one. It's about personal core data, i.e. name address etc. I would like to come up with a mapping of these keys in an automated way. I've read about HMM to use for this. However, I'm still gathering some information of some feasible and standard ways to do it. I'm looking therefore for some reference which describes a possible solution to this.

Comment: Dated but relevant: [A survey of approaches to automatic schema matching](https://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/file/VLDBJ-Dec2001.pdf). More recent book: [Ontology Matching](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642387203).

Comment: @Emre I came across the book. How detailed is it about machine learning techniques to use? The previews I saw looked more like a manuel and not very automated approach

Comment: There's brief coverage of ML in 7.5. See also _Schema Matching and Mapping_ and [Ontology matching: A literature review](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.eswa.2014.08.032). I also came across [this tool](http://www.biggorilla.org/schema-matching-and-merging/). If I had to do this myself I'd look into regression between graph embeddings, or _graph matching_ with a PGM, e.g., like [A Probabilistic-Logical Framework for Ontology Matching](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI10/paper/viewPaper/1744), or [Markov network based ontology matching](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcss.2011.02.014).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Michael Stonebraker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Stonebraker) started a company that claims to do just that, schema matching using machine learning:

https://www.tamr.com/

Their site no longer has many details on their approach but [this](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2014/05/tamr-new-frontier-big-data-curation.html) article talks about some of the techniques they used, like :

> - Perform fuzzy string comparisons over attribute names using trigram cosine    similarity.
> - Treats a column of data as a document and tokenize its    values with a standard full text parser. Then, measure TF-IDF cosine
>     similarity between columns. This method is suitable for text fields.
> - Use minimum description length (MDL) to compare values of two    attributes.
> - Compute the ratio of the size of the intersection of two    columns' data to the size of their union. This method is well suited
>     for categorical fields with small number of values.
> - Compute Welch's t-test for a pair of columns that contain numeric values and get the probability the columns were drawn from the same
>     distribution.